# Scroll horizontal in disabled edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

An edittext turn enabled or disabled in code (if "EDIT" button is pressed or not).

The problem is: if edittext contains a large text and his status is disabled, i can't scroll horizontal for view all text. (if his status is enabled, i can scroll horizontally normally)

Comment: Keep your edittext in scrollview.

Comment: What if the EditText is female?

Answer (score 0):

if you wrap your `EditText` in  `HorizontalScrollView` the user can scroll it horizontally even if EditText is disabled :

```
<HorizontalScrollview
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <EditText
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried:

                HorizontalScrollView myScroll = new HorizontalScrollView(getApplicationContext());
                myScroll.addView(myEditText);
                secondMatrix_rows[i].addView(myScroll);

It doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following parameters in the edittext.

```
edittext.setFocusable(false);
edittext.setClickable(false);
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
edittext.setEnabled(true);
edittext.setKeyListener(null);
edittext.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

So it will work as the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Edittext in XML

```
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_myEdtitText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:maxLines="1"

                            />
```

and in JAVA add this,

```
 et_myEdtitText.setKeyListener(null);
```

Now i won't be able to add any text in Edittext. Because, i have disabled KeyListener, But i will be able to scroll your Edittext horizontally